# What is the difference between the area of the square and the area of the circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, area

Use the following information to answer the question:

The circle has a radius of 3x and is inscribed inside the square.

I've researched this particular topic, but I've come up with nothing.

Choices:
A. 3x(4-)
B. x²(-4)
C. 9x²(4-)
D. 9x(4+)
E. 3x²(1-)

The area of a circle is pi times the radius squared (A = π r²).
The area of a square is equal to (side) × (side) square units.

Once you have found the area of the circle and square, subtract them for your final answer.

Comment: Latex your answer please. Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Diagram of circle inscribed in square]

Using the above image for reference:

Area of square:
$$A_s = s^2 = (2*3x)^2 = 36x^2$$
Area of circle:
$$A_c = \pi * r^2 = \pi *(3x)^2 = 9\pi x^2$$
Difference:
$$A_s-A_c = 36x^2 - 9\pi x^2 = 9x^2(4-\pi)$$
And so my answer would be C.